# Does ShinyApps.io support environment variables and secrets with Shiny for Python?

Tags: python, shinyapps, py-shiny

I'm trying to use an API key in a Python Shiny app that I want to push to ShinyApps.io - I've been struggling to find a way to do this with the Python packages.